# Application of Properties of Radon Nikodym Thm

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification, radon-nikodym

Let $\mu$ and $\nu$ be finite positive measures on a measurable space $(X,\mathcal{A})$, which are equivalent (i.e., $\nu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\mu$ and $\mu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\nu$). Let $\lambda = \mu + \nu$. Show that the Radon-Nikodym derivative satisfies  $0 < \frac{d\nu}{d\lambda}< 1$.

My attempt: Is this sketch of the proof fine?

1- Using the fact the$\mu , \nu$ are positive measures and $\lambda = \mu + \nu$, we can see that $\mu\ll \lambda$, $ \nu \ll \lambda$

2- Showing that $\frac{d\nu}{d\lambda}>0$ and  $\frac{d\mu}{d\lambda}>0$ (How do I show this?)

3- It is enough to prove the property that $ \frac{d(\nu+\mu)}{d\lambda}=\frac{d\nu}{d\lambda}+\frac{d\mu}{d\lambda}$

4- so by  $\lambda = \mu + \nu$ , we'd have $ \frac{d\lambda}{d\lambda}=\frac{d\nu}{d\lambda}+\frac{d\mu}{d\lambda}$ $\implies$ $\frac{d\nu}{d\lambda} = 1- \frac{d\mu}{d\lambda} \implies$  $0 < \frac{d\nu}{d\lambda}< 1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us show that $0<\frac {d\nu} {d\lambda} <1$ almost everywhere w.r.t. $\lambda$ [hence also w.r.t. $\mu$ and w.r.t. $\nu$].

Let $E=\{ \frac {d\nu} {d\lambda}=0\}$. Then $\nu (E)=\int_E \frac {d\nu} {d\lambda} d\lambda =0$. But $\mu << \nu$ so we also get $\mu (E)=0$. Adding these two we get $\lambda (E)=0$ which means $\frac {d\nu} {d\lambda} >0$ a.e. w.r.t. $\lambda$.

To prove that $\frac {d\nu} {d\lambda} <1$ a.e. w.r.t. $\lambda$ simply repeat the above argument with $\mu$ and $\nu$ interchanged to get $\frac {d\mu} {d\lambda} >0$ a.e. w.r.t. $\lambda$ and this is equivalent to $\frac {d\nu} {d\lambda} <1$ a.e. w.r.t. $\lambda$.

Comment: I did not get how $\frac {d\nu} {d\lambda} >0$ and $\frac {d\mu} {d\lambda} >0$ would gives $\frac {d\nu} {d\lambda} <1$.

Comment: Just verify from definition of Radon Nikodym derivative that $\frac {d\mu} {d\lambda} +\frac {d\nu} {d\lambda}=1$ a.e. w.r.t. $\lambda$.

Comment: can I also write that as of 4 I wrote above?

Comment: Yes, 4) is right.